# Is backup of a scientific book on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-ness

Is this question on topic?

I am an amateur mathematician.

Currently I have two Git repositories (at BitBucket.org and GitHub.com) with copies of my book.

Is it worth to add even more Git repositories to make sure that my book will survive even if I die?

Comment: I don't think we can answer that, it'll be probably closed because it depends too much on your personal preferences.

Comment: To answer the question, 'is this question on topic', I believe the question is too specific (about the use of a particular website). Perhaps a better question would be 'what is the best way to ensure code will be accessible in the future?' This will extend much more beyond particular websites and will be focused more on techniques and strategies which may be more applicable to academia in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question is probably not on-topic, because:

- It really has nothing to do with academia. You're asking how to ensure your work exists in perpetuity, which is a concern with any user-created content.
- It's unlikely to have a single correct answer, and would probably end up as a discussion on various ways to store materials both online and offline.